# Spring Boot - Access @Repository in org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have an Spring Data JPA which **needs to lookup up the name of a table in another lookup table.**

I have used a subclass of :

[org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/boot/model/naming/PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl.html)

And set the value `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.physical_naming_strategy`, to this subclass.

The subclass is as follows:

```
@Component
public class LookupNamingStategy extends PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl {

    @Autowired
    private LookupRepo repo;

    @Override
    public Identifier toPhysicalTableName(Identifier logicalName, JdbcEnvironment context) {
        if(logicalName.getCanonicalName().equalsIgnoreCase("LOOKUP"))
            return super.toPhysicalTableName(logicalName, context);

        LookUp lookUp = repo.findFirstByOrderById();
        return Identifier.toIdentifier(lookUp.getTable_name());
    }
}
```

The problem with this it creates **a circular dependency**. During the time of initialization, it is unable to access the `LookupRepo` as it is being initialized.

**All I want to do is set the table name from another defined table. The table name is decided at runtime.**

Is there anyway I can programmatically check if the bean is being initialized and skip any code that accesses it ?

Any other way this can be remedied ?

Answer (score 0):

This method does not work as NamingStrategy is not called every time the query is called.